# Writing binary data to file with JScript/VBScript

Tags: vbscript, jscript

I used FileSystemObject's CreateTextFile and Write methods to write binary data to a file, however I found that Write method refused to write bytes that are more than 0x80. Here is an example:

```javascript
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var fil = fso.CreateTextFile("test.bin", true);
f.Write("\x00 ... \x7F"); // This works fine
f.Write("\x80 ... \xFF"); // This fails
f.Close();
```

How can I avoid this problem? What is the best way write binary files with JScript/VBScript?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your Problem in VBScript. `f.Write Chr(&hFF)` works just fine.

Comment: `ADODB.Stream` is an object you can use to read/write text and binary files in  `VBScript`...

Comment: I also failed to write '\x80', but can write '€' which result in '\x80'